# How do you get express to work on Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm

I have a app on Heroku and when I run `node server.js` it's throwing a error and saying Error: Cannot find module 'express'.

I've cleared the npm cache, rebuilt the app, checked the package.json & dependencies. Nothing much is working for me and I'm just looking for solutions now.

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Trying to get the app to start.

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "SCOGEAgent",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A simple Blockstack app",
  "main": "index",
  "scripts": {
    "browserify": "browserify requires.js -o public/bundle.js",
    "start": "run browserify & node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/blockstack/hello-blockstack.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/blockstack/hello-blockstack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/blockstack/hello-blockstack#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "opn": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "blockstack": "^18.0.4",
    "express-ws": "^4.0.0",
    "json-pointer": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "websocket-stream": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: r u sure, you follow all of this as mention here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: "I've cleared the npm cache"—how, exactly? Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json`. Is your `node_modules/` tracked (it shouldn't be)?

Comment: I added the package.json to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express should be in your `dependencies` not `devDependencies`. Here's how you know where to put your third-party dependencies.

- Does the app need the dependency to run? Put it in `dependencies`
- Does the app need the dependency to build, test, lint, or any other
  task for development? Put it in `devDependencies`.

The only time this gets fuzzy is when you need to build the project before you run it. Then some of your build dependencies might be placed in `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`. I'm sure there is a more professional way to manage this but that's how I do it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I changed the dependencies around and did `npm install` and `node server.js` and it worked fine. Thank you.